# WiX: disable reboot for EXE package

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, setup-project, restart

I am currently developing a setup (MSI) and a bootstrapper project with *Windows Installer XML*. The bootstrapper must install three additional drivers too.
These Drivers are EXE packages that want to restart after installation. I know that three restarts are unnecessary - only one at the end is required.

Is it possible to disable the restart for packages in my chain?

Comment: The issue is very likely to be what those executables do and if they have a command line option that suppresses a reboot - many of them do. WiX can't prevent a reboot coming directly from code inside an exe that WiX has no control over!

Comment: @PhilDW I performed a research and think there is no command line switch or similar. 
I think you are right. If you post you comment as an answer I will mark it as the answer.